# Do Hamiltonian operators preserve square integrability?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, hamiltonian

Is Hamiltonian operator an operator that preserves the property of square integrability?

Comment: Please provide some more details/equations, and point out where you have been stuck in attempting to prove/disprove this, @y255yan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether the question is, if the following expression is finite:
$$
\Vert H | \psi \rangle \Vert^2= \langle \psi | H^{\dagger} H | \psi \rangle = \sum_{n, m} c_n^{*} c_m \lambda_n^{*} \lambda_m \langle \psi_n^{*} | \psi_m  \rangle = \sum_{n} |c_n|^2|\lambda_n|^2
$$
Where in second equality we have assumed, that $| \psi_m  \rangle$  form an orthogonal basis, then it is true, when the spectrum is bounded, or eigenvalues decay sufficiently fast, so that the series (integral in the continuum case) converges.

Comment: I agree with you. Now I'm pretty confusing about what does it actually mean by saying Hamiltonian operator is a linear operator that acts on Hilbert space? Shouldn't a linear operator on Hilbert space send a square integrable function to a square integrable function?